# Prove the real radical is an ideal

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, abstract-algebra

How does one prove that the **real** radical of an ideal $I$ in the real polynomial ring $\mathbb{R}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ is an ideal. (NOT to be confused the radical of an ideal)

I am using the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_radical) definition of the real ideal as well.

Consider $f,h$ in the real radical. both have a corresponding integers $m,n$ and a sequence of functions such that its sum of squares are in the ideal $I$. in other words, $f^{2m},g^{2n}$ can be written as a sum of squared functions plus a function in ideal I. consider the expansion of $(f+h)^{mn}$. the goal is to show that this expansion can be written as a sum of squared functions plus a sum of functions in ideal $I$. But when you expand it, this is not at all clear. even if you consider $(f+h)^{2m+2n}$, its not clear either.

Is there are more intuitive approach to showing this?

Comment: It is better to incorporate the context in question. For example, an ideal $I$ of what?

Comment: @Z.M i have updated the question to be more specific. But its a rather general question anyways

Comment: Try $(f+g)^{2m+2n}$. This probably doesn't belong on MO.

Comment: @KevinCasto I know, I felt that it wasnt really an MO question. But I really didn't get much help over there. Thank you for your suggestion. But i did try already with 2m+2n without any success

Comment: Take $(f+h)^{2m+2n}$ and expand it using binomial theorem. You will obtain a sum of terms each of which is a multiple of $f^{2m}$ or $h^{2n}$.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek i mean, sure i already did that. but i really don't see at all how the fact that $f^{2m}$ and $g^{2n}$ are factors in the sum make any difference?

Comment: $f^{2m}$ and $g^{2n}$ are not in the ideal $I$ either. And even if you substitute in the sum of square polynomials they are equal to, we havent actually shown anything

Comment: By the binomial theorem, $-(f+g)^{2m+2n}=f^{2m}p+g^{2n}q$ for some polynomials $p$ and $q$. Thus, $-(f+g)^{2m+2n}=-f^{2m}((p-1)/2)^2-g^{2n}((q-1)/2)^2+(f^m(p+1)/2)^2+(g^n(q+1)/2)^2$. I hope you can finish it from there.

Comment: (Better yet, it even works over rings where $2$ is not invertible: $-(f+g)^{2m+2n}=-f^{2m}p^2-g^{2n}q^2+(f^m(p+1))^2+(g^n(q+1))^2+(f+g)^{2m+2n}$.)